# 'Unable to Find User ContainerUser' when building Windows Dockerfile via Actions Runner

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, nano-server

When building my windows dockerfile (.net core nano)...

`docker build -f *** -t ***:*** --build-arg ARG1=foo --build-arg ARG2=bar .`

I'm getting an error during the build that occurs in response to my first `RUN` command. The command will fail with the following message:

`ERROR: failed to solve: process "cmd /S /C dotnet restore \"myproject.csproj\"" did not complete successfully: unable to find user ContainerUser: invalid argument`

In my case this is a `dotnet restore` command but any `RUN` statement will result in:

`unable to find user ContainerUser: invalid argument`

Note that the default user for windows nanoserver containers is `ContainerUser`. If I designate another user eg. `USER ContainerAdministrator` prior to the `RUN` statement, the same failure occurs for that user too (`unable to find user ContainerAdministrator: invalid argument`).

Dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myproject.csproj", "myproject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "myproject/myproject.csproj"  <--- Error thrown here (user not found)
```

**The caveat is that this is only occuring when ran from a github actions workflow on a self-hosted windows runner**. The Dockerfile builds in other environments no problem and has been deployed successfully. However I don't have access to the runner, so I'm trying to troubleshoot from afar.

Any ideas as to what would cause the user to not be found in the container? I'm having a hard time finding any documentation around this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue until I removed the **nanoserver** part of the FROM statement

Try:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
```

Rather than:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
```